# What does the 300 level webcast or speak mean (in MSDN, webcast, trainig, etc.)?

Tags: levels

I suppose this is either some Microsoft or even US-wide scheme.
However I have no idea what does 300, 400, etc. mean.
Can someone please explain this?
What do those numbers mean? 
Is it MS thing or is it in wider usage?

Comment: It's an MS thing:
http://support.microsoft.com/gp/webcastlevels

Answer (score 6):

As the other links are dead, [I have a new one](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ieitpro/archive/2006/09/29/459944.aspx).

Quote:

> **Level 100 Description:**
>   Introductory and overview material. Assumes
>   little or no expertise with topic and covers topic concepts,
>   functions, features, and benefits.   
> **Level 200 Description:**
>   Intermediate material. Assumes 100-level knowledge and provides
>   specific details about the topic.   
> **Level 300 Description:**
>  Advanced
>   material. Assumes 200-level knowledge, in-depth understanding of
>   features in a real-world environment, and strong coding skills.
>   Provides a detailed technical overview of a subset of
>   product/technology features, covering architecture, performance,
>   migration, deployment, and development.   
> **Level 400 Description:**
>   Expert material. Assumes a deep level of technical knowledge and
>   experience and a detailed, thorough understanding of topic. Provides
>   expert-to-expert interaction and coverage of specialized topics.

[And here is another link about Microsoft Training Levels](http://www.misglobaltech.com.au/page/55-microsoft-training-level-descriptions).

Answer (score 2):

The 100, 200, ... vernacular is used widely in colleges in the US.  Generally 100 level classes are for freshman (first year), 200 for sophomores (second year), 300's for juniors (third year), etc.

Microsoft has a listing of their usage (see Kurt's post)

Comment: That's what I supposed (that it still is somehow related to colleges in US). 
Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

This is roughly modelled on the way college courses are typically numbered (at least here in the US that I'm aware of).

See:
[College Course Numbers @ Everything2](http://everything2.com/title/College%2520Course%2520Numbers)